# What is a hermaphroditic USB AB receptacle?

Tags: usb, connector

[Wikipedia's page on USB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) describes a "hermaphroditic AB receptacle". I cannot find any information on it - No pictures, specs or anything. Is this a single connector? Or have I missed the point?

Comment: Sounds like it's about this connector. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/USB_Micro-AB_receptacle.jpg. It can behave as both an upstream or downstream port (Being USB OTG) so it can be either A or B. This image shows the two cables that can be plugged in. https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-59159668156b173b7fadcf846fda8a6c-c?convert_to_webp=true

Comment: @chamod Excellent, thanks - you should put that in an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/USB_Micro-AB_receptacle.jpg) connector.

[image]
Mobile devices have this port that can behave as an upstream or downstream port (Being USB OTG) so it can be either A or B. [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#Micro_connectors) has photos of the two types of cables that can be plugged in.

[image: Micro-A and Micro-B]